# IntelliJ not setting the system property for my project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, openjdk-11

I am trying to set and retrieve a System Property. In my IntelliJ I have placed the -D parameter correctly in the Edit Configurations -> Program Arguments.
However, when the project is executed, this value is not added to the running JVM.
If i add a system variable programatically as seen in my example "Hey", I can see the value.

You can see in my screenshot that the -D system parameter passed can be see in the args during runtime, but its not in the JVM system properties...

[image]

Comment: you think that just by passing a String, you are altering the System properties??

Comment: @Stultuske, I am passing the string in run configurations in IntelliJ, isnt that what IntelliJ has to do ? regardless if i bundle my application and still pass the -Dconfig=value, it doesn't work (returns null).

Comment: you are passing it as a command line argument. It's just considered a String

Comment: I don't think IntelliJ can actually parse the Program Arguments without it being at run time, I.E as you image shows it's correct when the program runs because until IntelliJ is actively running your application it has no idea how that argument might be used.

Comment: Thanks guys, it was my fault indeed. I was passing the value not in the VM argument but in the Program Arguments.